# Evaluate $\dot{v}=-\frac{\gamma}{m}v+g$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

> Solve: $$\dot{v}=-\frac{\gamma}{m}v+g$$
>
> Where $\gamma,m,g$ are constants

I have to to separate the equation as $\dot{v}=\frac{dv}{dt}$
and got to:

$$\frac{dv-g}{v}=-\frac{\gamma}{m}dt$$

Comment: What about dividing by r.h.s?
$$
\frac{\text d v}{g - \frac{\gamma}{m} v} = \text d t
$$

Comment: @Harry49 so we get $\frac{ln(g-\frac{\gamma}{m}v)}{-\frac{\gamma}{m}}=dt$? integrating both sides and taking exponent gives $v=\frac{m}{\gamma}(g-e^t)$?

Comment: @newhere close, but don't forget to do the reverse chain rule when you integrate. You're missing some constants in from of the $\ln$. Also don't forget you get a constant of integration somewhere

Comment: I think it's easier to use the method of integrating factor. Or $v=v_h+v_p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rearrangement is incorrect; what you can condlude is that $\frac{dv/dt-g}{v}=-\frac{\gamma}{m}$, but note that cross-multiplying by $dt$ changes $g$ to $gdt$. Harry49 has already explained how to solve the problem by separation, so I'll mention another method, that of integration factors.

Our original equation is $\dot{v}+Pv=Q$ with $P:=\frac{\gamma}{m},\,Q:=g$, neither of which depend on $v$. The procedure I'm about to describe does require this, but it allows for a $t$-dependence.

Write $R:=\exp\int Pdt$ so $R^\prime=RP,\,(Rv)^\prime=RQ,\,v=R^{-1}\int RQdt$. With indefinite integration $P$ ($R$) is determined up to an additive (multiplicative) constant, while $v$ is determined up to $CR$ with $C$ an integration constant, regardless of which antiderivative of $P$ is chosen in defining $R$.

In the case at hand $v=e^{-\gamma t/m}\int ge^{\gamma t/m} dt=Ce^{-\gamma t/m}+\frac{mg}{\gamma}$. If $v_0$ denotes the $t=0$ value of $v$, $v=(v_0-\frac{mg}{\gamma})e^{-\gamma t/m}+\frac{mg}{\gamma}$.

Edit: as for separation, we get $t-t_0=-\frac{m}{\gamma}\ln |g-\frac{\gamma v}{m}|\implies v=g\mp\frac{m}{\gamma}\exp\frac{\gamma (t-t_0)}{m}$, which can be manipulated in the same way.

Comment: Taking $R=e^{\frac{\gamma}{m}t}$ I got $v=\frac{mg}{\gamma}$ is it correct?

Comment: @newhere Your result is just a constant. You should get $e^{-\gamma t/m}\int ge^{\gamma t/m}dt$, but bear in mind the integral includes an integration constant.

Comment: $\dot{v}+\frac{\gamma}{m}v=g$ taking integration factor $R=e^{\int \frac{\gamma}{m}dt}=e^{\frac{\gamma}{m}t}$ so $e^{ \frac{\gamma}{m}t}\dot{v}+e^{\frac{\gamma}{m}t}\frac{\gamma}{m}v=e^{ \frac{\gamma}{m}t}g$ setting $k=\frac{\gamma}{m}$ we have $e^{kt}\dot{v}+e^{kt}kv=e^{ kt}g$ integrating both sides we get $e^{kt}v=\frac{e^{ kt}}{k}g+c$

Comment: @newhere With $R=\exp\frac{\gamma t}{m}$ we have $\int RQ dt=\frac{mg}{\gamma}\exp\frac{\gamma t}{m}+C$ so $v=\frac{mg}{\gamma}+C\exp\frac{-\gamma t}{m}$.

Comment: Just found where I lost the constant, thanks!!!